# 6 Month Daily Survey Database with Identical Fields

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create a database to manage my 50+ and growing excel tables
* I'm surveying employees over time
*I ask them a question and they can answer 1 of 8 responses
*The Employees have different work schedules, so it's not the exact same people everyday

The tables are..... in 4 columns  ( I have a table for each day) 50+ Days

**Name of Worker   Morning-Question   11am-Question     2pm-Question**

I put the tables into MySQL, I'm trying to pull up queries for name= "Tony James" so I can see all of his responses in the 50 days, any suggestions??  of if you have any better idea's to structure the information I would be most appreciative,

Thanks

Stacy

Answer (score 0):

You should create a users table like this:

```
ID    Name
1     Tony James
```

Then in the other table reference that like so:

```
ID    UserID     Morning-Question     11am-Question     2pm-Question
1     1          blah blah            blah blah         blah blah
```

You could then run this query:

```
Select * from Questions q
join Users u
on q.UserID = u.id
where u.name = 'Tony James'
```

Comment: Thanks will try running that.